# Using excel2json to convert to JSON - issue with dates

Tags: python, json, xls

I am trying to use excel2json to convert a .xls file to JSON.
The excel file has 3 columns:

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3
1           BOB         1/1/2020
2           SALLY       1/4/2020
```

I used:

```
import excel2json
excel2json.convert_from_file('test.xls')
```

It works well for all but the date column. The dates given in the JSON file are random numbers, for example: 43831.0

Where is this coming from? How can I keep the date the same format in JSON?

Comment: Is the issue resolved? Is so, please mark the answer as accepted to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not random, you need to further process the ordinal representation of the date inside excel into `datetime` objects and then back into their string representations further:

```
from datetime import datetime
excel_date = 43831
dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + excel_date - 2)
dt_string = dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

You can create a function which basically converts `excel_date` to its string representation using the above logic and map it to the list of your ordinal representations of dates in your JSON.